# Grails - bind multiple request parameters with same name to List using command object

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm trying to figure out how to bind request params with the same name to a List using a command object.

My command object currently looks like:

```
class EventSaleDataCommand {
    List<Long> eventIds

    static constraints = {
        eventIds nullable: false
    }
}
```

The problem with this command object is it will allow urls such as `appName/controllerName/actionName?eventIds=&eventsIds=` to pass through the validation process even though the eventIds params is empty.

I'd like to validate that at least one of the eventIds is not empty so I'm wondering what the best approach to take is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may give you what you want:

```
class EventSaleDataCommand {
    List<Long> eventIds

    static constraints = {
        eventIds validator: { val ->
            val.any {
                it != null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will validate that at least one of the elements is non-null.